# why my koa-passport authenticate parameter user is always undefined?

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js, koa2, koa-passport

I'm trying to use koa-passport for koa2, and followed the examples of the author, but i always get "**Unauthorized**". I used the console.log and found that it even **not** hit the **serializeUser**.

```
var UserLogin = async (ctx, next) =>{
    return passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info, status) {
        if (user === false) {
            ctx.body = { success: false }
        } else {
            ctx.body = { success: true }
            return ctx.login(user)
        }
    })(ctx, next);
};
```

And then I searched on the web and found another writing of router, it goes to the **serializeUser** but the **done(null, user.id)** threw error that "**cannot get id from undefined**".

```
let middleware = passport.authenticate('local', async(user, info) => {
        if (user === false) {
            ctx.status = 401;
        } else {
          await ctx.login(ctx.user, function(err){
              console.log("Error:\n- " + err);
          })
          ctx.body = { user: user }
        }
      });
    await middleware.call(this, ctx, next)
```

The auth.js are showed below. Also I followed [koa-passport example from the author](https://github.com/rkusa/koa-passport-example/blob/master/auth.js) here and tried to use **session**, but every request i sent will get a TypeError said "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined". But I think this is not the core problem of authentication, but for reference if that really is.

```
const passport = require('koa-passport')
const fetchUser = (() => {
  const user = { id: 1, username: 'name', password: 'pass', isAdmin: 'false' };
  return async function() {
    return user
  }
})()

const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  fetchUser()
    .then(user => {
      if (username === user.username && password === user.password) {
          done(null, user)
      } else {
        done(null, false)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => done(err))
}))

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id)
})

passport.deserializeUser(async function(id, done) {
  try {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    done(null, user)
  } catch(err) {
    done(err)
  }
})

module.exports = passport;
```

By the way when I use the simple default one, it will just give me a "Not found". But through console.log I can see it actually got into the *loginPass*.

```
var loginPass = async (ctx, next) =>{
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/myApp',
        failureRedirect: '/'
    });
};
```

In server.js:

```
// Sessions
const convert = require('koa-convert'); 
const session = require('koa-generic-session');
app.keys = ['mySecret'];
app.use(convert(session()));

// authentication
passport = require('./auth');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Thanks a lot for any help!!! :D